# Shell script csv to german readable excel

Tags: csv, encoding, sh, powershell-2.0

I have a `UTF-8` encoded csv which uses `,` as delimiter and `.` for decimals.

To make it work with German excel, I *think* I need `latin1` encoding `;` as delimiter and `,` for decimals.

Here is my shell script I have so far. (I am working on a Mac and it is supposed to work on Mac, no other os needed)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

# replace , to ; and . to ,
tr , ';' < $FILE > de1$FILE
tr '.' ',' < de1$FILE > de2$FILE

# change encoding
iconv -f UTF-8 -t LATIN1 < de2$FILE > de3$FILE
open de3$FILE
```

My Problem:

If I open with excel ö and other German special characters are still messed up.

This is the input csv

```
Göttingen, ä, 
ü, pü
```

This is the output when I open with excel

[image]

or here in plain text:

```
Gˆttingen  ‰
¸ p¸
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] (pictures are unwelcome) and maybe show more mojibake… Hard to guess from a single case… BTW, Excel _can_ read UTF-8 and delimiters as well as decimals are configurable while importing a csv file…

Comment: Hey JosefZ, this is my full script. What are you missing for this to be a minimum reproducible example?
mojibake?

Comment: The shell script looks OK. What if you use `open de2$FILE`?